# Combination of multiple joins in EclipseLink-Query

Tags: java, sql, jpa, join, eclipselink

I currently select multiple persons with a query that filters for name/forename/position from an input-string.

```
list = dao.loadQuery("SELECT b FROM person b JOIN b.positionList pl WHERE b.forename LIKE '%" + input + "%' OR b.name LIKE '%" + input + "%' OR pl.name Like '%" + input + "%'");
```

Now I am puzzled about how to add the functionality to filter for a certain skill a person has. It would be easy to make it one way or the other, but I need both joins, so the user can search for persons with the name/forename/position/skill provided.

Thank you in advance

Solution:

```
list = dao.loadQuery("SELECT b FROM person b JOIN b.positionList pl JOIN b.skillListe sl WHERE b.forename LIKE '%" + input + "%' OR b.name LIKE '%" + input + "%' OR pl.name Like '%" + input + "% OR sl.name Like '%" + input + "%'");
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for or why it is more difficult from what you have.  Can you not just join skill as you have to position?

Comment: I feel pretty dumb now. just adding another "JOIN b.skillList sl" did the job. don't ask me why thought too complicated. thank you @Chris for the inspiration!